# Переписать с использование Java 8 Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

```
private int chooseTaxi(District whereIsClient) {
    int taxiIndex = 0;
    int distance;
    int minDistance = 10;
    for (Taxi taxi : taxis) {
        if ((distance = District.calcDistance(taxi.getLocation(), whereIsClient)) < minDistance) {
            minDistance = distance;
            taxiIndex = taxis.indexOf(taxi);
        }
    }
    return taxiIndex;
}
```

Метод должен возвратить индекс такси, для которого будет выгоднее всего подъехать к whereIsClient. taxis - LinkedList, calcDistance - вычисляет расстояние между клиентом и такси. Как это переписать с использованием stream? Если возможно, конечно.

Comment: А Вам это нужно просто так для удобства или Вы приследуете конкретную цель?

Answer (score 2):

Можно написать следующим образом:

```
int taxiIndex = taxis.stream()
    .min(Comparator.comparing(
        taxi -> District.calcDistance(taxi.getLocation(), whereIsClient)
    ))
    .map(taxis::indexOf)
    .orElse(-1);
```

Comment: у вас нет фильтра, что дистанция меньше 10 и в оригинале возвращается 0, а не -1

Comment: @AndrewBystrov поменять -1 на 0 не составит труда, как мне кажется, так же, как и добавить нужные фильтрации при необходимости